# Laravel giving 404 error even though user not authenticated

Tags: laravel

I am creating an api using Laravel 4.1. I am having problem with authentication and custom errors. I want to check first if the user is authenticated and then show error message. For example localhost:8080/trips/1 is not a valid a resource; if I go to that url it giving me 404 not found error even though I am not authenticated. My point is to check the authentication first then the errors. I am using laravel http basic authentication. Here is my filter code:

```
Route::filter('api.auth', function()
{

    if (!Request::getUser())
    {
        App::abort(401, 'A valid API key is required');
    }

    $user = User::where('api_key', '=', Request::getUser())->first();

    if (!$user)
    {
        App::abort(401);
    }

    Auth::login($user);
});
```

Here is my custom errors:

```
App::error(function(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException $e, $code)
{
    $headers = $e->getHeaders();

    switch ($code)
    {
        case 401:
            $default_message = 'Invalid API key';
            $headers['WWW-Authenticate'] = 'Basic realm="REST API"';
        break;

        case 403:
            $default_message = 'Insufficient privileges to perform this action';
        break;

        case 404:
            $default_message = 'The requested resource was not found';
        break;

        default:
            $default_message = 'An error was encountered';
    }

    return Response::json(array(
        'error' => $e->getMessage() ?: $default_message,
    ), $code, $headers);
});
```

Here is my routes:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'api.auth'), function()
{

    Route::resource('trips', 'TripController', array(
        'except' => array('create', 'edit')
    ));
});
```

The error code is executing before the filters thats why I am getting 404 error instead of getting 401. Is there any way to execute filter first then the error ?

Comment: Still getting this? Can't replicate, keeps showing 401 first.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue too and the way I worked around it (though I was not a fan at all) was doing the following inside the group(s) that don't contain a route sending requests to a controller's index method:

```
Route::any('/', function(){});
```

Granted, this shouldn't be how it works, the filter should trigger no matter what.